# How to pass unspecified number of parameters to setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I need to create an interval wrapper to track if it has been cleared.

The number of parameters to pass to the interval callback should be variable. So this is the code (not working) I implemented to test it:

```js
function MyInterval() {
  var id = setInterval.apply(this, arguments); // NOT VALID!!
  this.cleared = false;
  this.clear = function() {
    this.cleared = true;
    clearInterval(id);
  };
}

var x = 2;
var y = 3;
var fn = function() {
  x = x + y;
  console.log(x);
};
var interval = new MyInterval(fn, 5000, x, y);
```

Comment: Use an object literal.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Untrue, [param1, param2, and so forth, are additional parameters that are passed through to the function specified by func.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) ...

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Sorry buddy. Just checked.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl: They are on modern browsers. They aren't on older browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the call to `setInterval`, `this` must refer to the global object, so instead of `this`, you want `window` in your constructor:

```
var id = setInterval.apply(window, arguments);
// here -------------------^
```

(or in loose mode you could use `undefined` or `null`.)

Then it works, at least on browsers where `setInterval` is a real JavaScript function and therefore has `apply`:

```js
function MyInterval() {
  var id = setInterval.apply(window, arguments);
  this.cleared = false;
  this.clear = function() {
    this.cleared = true;
    clearInterval(id);
  };
}

var x = 2;
var y = 3;
var fn = function() {
  x = x + y;
  log(x);
};
var interval = new MyInterval(fn, 500, x, y);
setTimeout(function() {
  interval.clear();
}, 3000);

function log(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

**Note**, though, that host-provided functions are only required to be callable, they are *not* required to inherit from `Function.prototype` and so they're not required/guaranteed to have `apply`. Modern browsers ensure they do, but earlier ones (IE8, for instance) did not. I can't speak to how well-supported `apply` is on `setInterval`.

If you need to support browsers that may not have it, just to use your own function:

```
function MyInterval(handler, interval) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
  var tick = function() {
    handler.apply(undefined, args);
  };
  var id = setInterval(tick, interval);
  this.cleared = false;
  this.clear = function() {
    this.cleared = true;
    clearInterval(id);
  };
}
```

This also has the advantage that it works even on browsers that don't support additional args on `setInterval` (fairly old ones).

Example:

```js
function MyInterval(handler, interval) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
  var tick = function() {
    handler.apply(undefined, args);
  };
  var id = setInterval(tick, interval);
  this.cleared = false;
  this.clear = function() {
    this.cleared = true;
    clearInterval(id);
  };
}

var x = 2;
var y = 3;
var fn = function() {
  x = x + y;
  log(x);
};
var interval = new MyInterval(fn, 500, x, y);
setTimeout(function() {
  interval.clear();
}, 3000);

function log(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

You might be tempted to use the new ES2015 spread operator:

```
var id = setInterval(...arguments);
```

...but note that if you transpile (and right now you'd have to), it ends up being an `apply` call, and so you have the issue of whether `apply` is supported.

Comment: No problem with dinosaur versions like IE8. They're almost dead.

Comment: @user3514092: Your lips to God's ears (Net Apps says [7.5% market share globally](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0), which is down markedly from a few months ago), but beware niche browsers, such as on phones.

Comment: @t-j-crowder Despite that market share percentage, this code is going to be actually used in an enterprise application whose workers are already advised to use modern borwsers. It's not a website for the public in general. But thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @user3514092: Heck, lots of folks with public sites aren't bothering with IE8 support now either. BTW, I updated the "if `apply` isn't on `setInterval`" part of the answer with a *much* simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you pass an "options" parameter to your timeout.

```js
var MyInterval = (function(window) {
  return function(callbackFn, timeout, options) {
    var id = setInterval.apply(window, arguments);
    this.cleared = false;
    this.clear = function() {
      this.cleared = true;
      clearInterval(id);
    };
  }
}(window));

var fn = function(opts) {
  opts.x += opts.y;
  console.log('x = ', opts.x);
};
var opts = {
  x: 2,
  y: 3
};
var ms = 5000;

var interval = new MyInterval(fn, ms, opts);

// Bootstrap a custom logger. :)
console.log = function() {
  var logger = document.getElementById('logger');
  var el = document.createElement('LI');
  el.innerHTML = [].join.call(arguments, ' ');
  logger.appendChild(el);
  logger.scrollTop = logger.scrollHeight;
}
```

```css
body{background:#7F7F7F;}h1{background:#D7D7D7;margin-bottom:0;padding:0.15em;border-bottom:thin solid #AAA;color:#444}#logger{height:120px;margin-top:0;margin-left:0;padding-left:0;overflow:scroll;max-width:100%!important;overflow-x:hidden!important;font-family:monospace;background:#CCC}#logger li{list-style:none;counter-increment:step-counter;padding:.1em;border-bottom:thin solid #E7E7E7;background:#FFF}#logger li:nth-child(odd){background:#F7F7F7}#logger li::before{content:counter(step-counter);display:inline-block;width:1.4em;margin-right:.5em;padding:.25em .75em;font-size:1em;text-align:right;background-color:#E7E7E7;color:#6A6A6A;font-weight:700}
```

```html
<h1>Custom HTML Logger</h1><ol id="logger"></ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a utility function rather than a constructor to solve your issue.

```
function Wrapper(delay) {
  var isCleared,
      intervalId,
      intervalDelay = delay || 5e3; // default delay of 5 sec

  function clear() {
    if (!isCleared) {
      console.log('clearing interval');
      isCleared = true;
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }

  function setUpInterval(callback){
    var params = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    if (!callback) {
      throw new Error('Callback for interval expected');
    }

    params.unshift(intervalDelay);
    params.unshift(callback);

    intervalId = setInterval.apply(null, params);
  }

  return {
    setUp : setUpInterval,
    clear : clear
  }
}

function intervalCallback() {
  console.log([].slice.call(arguments).join(','));
}


var wrapper = Wrapper(1e3); // create wrapper with delay for interval


console.log('test case 1');
wrapper.setUp(intervalCallback, 'params', 'to', 'callback');

// call clear interval after 10sec
setTimeout(function() {
  wrapper.clear();
}, 10e3);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Upvote for your suggestion, and especially for the 5e3 notation for 5000. I didn't know it was possible to do that in Javascript.